# python whois for windows

Tags: python, windows, whois

I try to get whois in python. I use this
http://code.google.com/p/pywhois/
but it run only in linux. Is it posible to run it on windows? currently i get errors (because internal linux command whois used)

Comment: I found this link, not sure how helpful it will be but it deals with reverse DNS, which apparently, a user argues, is more reliable than whois anyways: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/46509-whois-like-functionality-windows

Comment: That's bogus, whois and DNS are for different things.  You can get the name server from DNS, where whois basically only provides a non-authoritative version of the same information.  Otherwise, they are for different purposes, and contain different sorts of information, and serve different needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows just like on Linux, pywhois gives an error if the `whois` program is not installed.  You could try [this whois](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897435.aspx), for example.

The reason, of course, is in [pywhois/**init**.py](http://code.google.com/p/pywhois/source/browse/trunk/pywhois/__init__.py), line 11:

```
r = subprocess.Popen(['whois', domain], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Clearly this line needs to run some existing, installed `whois` command-line program (which accepts the domain to look up as a commandline argument), whatever OS it's running on.

Comment: It should not be hard to replace this with a pure-Python implementation, though.  Basically `telnet whois.internic.net 43` and query for the domain you want, then follow the link it gives you.  Hint: `=google.com` works better than `google.com` but there is still quite some amounts of chaff to sort through.

Answer (score 1):

You could use :

```
os.system("whois %s" % hostname)
```

Or use `urllib` to connect **http://www.whois.net** and scrap content.

Comment: Please us `subprocess.Popen` instead of `os.system`

Comment: your first suggestion (with `subprocess`, not `os.system`) is exactly what `pywhois` uses (on any OS -- see my A with a single line quoted from pywhois's sources), with nice post-processing for parsing the results and making them more usable. You just need a `whois` installed and correctly working -- if your first suggestion works, so will `pywhois`!-)

Comment: @S.Lott Why not, but could you explain why ?

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/ "The subprocess module provides the following enhancements over
    previous functions:"  Summary: `subprocess.Popen` is better than `os.system`