# check domain availability in django

Tags: django, dns

I want to design a page that user enter domain names and the program check if it is available or not.I searched in web that took me several hours and finally no result.there were guidances in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523260/recommendations-for-domain-name-registrar-with-api-support) and also [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25129/how-to-check-if-domain-already-exists),but they didn't help me.I searched about `arcpy` in django,but that sounds like I can't use it in django,am I right?there were also some APIs but they were for PHP,Ruby and etc.If U have done something like this,would U mind tell me which API or library U have used?

**Edit:**

I think solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450339/python-get-whois) is good,but what's dependencies to use `subprocess` ?

**Edit:**
this is [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578943/error-when-using-pywhois)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one http://code.google.com/p/pywhois/

**EDIT:** [python whois for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450339/python-get-whois)

Comment: that sounds like great,this 2 lines of code are clear : >>> import pywhois
>>> w = pywhois.whois('google.com')
>>> w.expiration_date ,what about availability?are U sure It can check availability?

Comment: tnx,U directed me to this issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578943/error-when-using-pywhois/

Answer (score 0):

Django's URLField has a build in "verify_exists" method which you might be able to use. For more advanced behaviour I would just use urllib2 or some other library and add some functionality to your form