# How do I identify the user type of an IP address? Using python and requests/bs4/flask

Tags: python, ip, python-requests, ip-address

I'm using python with requests/bs4/flask and I'd like to identify the user type of an incoming IP request to my flask app.

http://ipleak.net identifies the type as residential, college, cafe, corporate, ect but they only check your IP.

[GeoIP2](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-precision-insights) is the API that drives ipleak.net for this  and the returned parameter is called User Type.

How do I identify an IP type without using their API? I'm okay with less accuracy/classification. Is there a public API for this? Or can I scrape it from a whois DB? Or can I identify it in another way?

Comment: There is a python-whois  lib http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580373/how-to-get-whois-info-by-ip-in-python-3/24586511#24586511

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I monitored the network traffic and found the call to check the type of IP. I wrote this function to check any IP that I pass to the function.

```
  import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  # check type of IP address
  def ip_check(ip):
        result = requests.get('https://ipleak.net/?mode=ajax&ip={}'.format(ip))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
        parse = soup.get_text()
        final = parse.replace('\xa0', '').replace(ip, '')
        return final
```