# How to Allow People to Use Whois on Linux Server

Tags: python, linux, whois

I want user to use Whois in my website, so I am using ubuntu server and Flask, now the problem is should I run a `os.system("whois " + domain)`. Because it will run the system for all the user who are using the site.

So is there anyway to run the system commands as an instance for every user? like the command only affect the current using user.

and also not only whois, I want to run my own binaries also like this

Comment: [click on this link ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580373/how-to-get-whois-info-by-ip-in-python-3)you may find your answer here. it will help you

Comment: They are only talking about whois in python libraries, but I need to run system binaries

Comment: I don't understand this bit: "Because it will run the system for all the user who are using the site."  Isn't that a question of how you handle sessions?

Comment: I don't get your issue. Define a flask route, get the user's address from the request object, and run the system binary.

Comment: what if 100 people doing that same thing, its going to create 100 process in server, I don't want to run it as a separate process, I want that process to be child of the Flask instance.

Comment: You have Python libraries to do whois calls, so no need to shell out to system.